# google photos api missing scope

Tags: php, scopes, google-photos-api

I am apart of an organization which stores event photos in a organization google photos account. We desire to display these photos via PHP on our website. I have followed the guidance of adding the API library for googlephotos and an OATH2 account.

First when configuring the OATH consent there is a scope field. We are unable to select or add any scopes.

Second just using the https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/sharedAlbums/get?authuser=2 it offers the ability to test the functionality without further coding. Logged in as the desired account on the above link and using what I believe is the shareToken string which is what you get when you copy the share URL and leave only the hash portion (such as: 'Buj7y3kTVo7KRUjr6'). Since we only have OATH2 enabled we deselect API key and hit execute which gives the following error:

```html
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid share token.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Looking under the "Scopes" I see: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing" but under the OATH credentials I see no way to add it. Seems to be stuck!

Thanks.